# Jquery Live with hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I have a list of hyperlinks. The list is called btnList.

When I do the following nothing returns:

```
    $("a.btnList").live('click', function () {

        alert($(this).attr("id"));
     }
```

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: If you're using jquery 1.7 or higher, use `.on` instead of `.live`. And wrap your code inside `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `live` anymore, as it has been deprecated. Use `on` and verify that your selector is correct. If your `a` tags are contained within a list with the class `btnList` then the following should work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnList a", function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using btnList as a class in your a tag.  You might have it as an id

Answer (score 0):

As per the JQuery document, http://api.jquery.com/live/

**As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.**